# Replace the binary part of a string?

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am having a string that has some binary data in it. The string in xml format, so before i am gonna proccess it i need to convert the binary data in the base64 format.
I am using a function called findXMLTag that will find the position of the start and the end of the data given the xml tag that contains it.
Now i am able to convert that data into base64 but i am having problems replacing the old binary data with my new base64 data.

The thing is that i can't use any type of string because when it locates a null char it will consider it as the terminating point of the string but in fact since i have binary data stored in the string then that null char can be part of my binary data.

So i guess i am looking for some kind of binary replacement and i can't figure out how to make it work.
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

This is the code that i am using to locate the start and the end of the data in an xml string.

```
std::vector<TForm1::Pair> TForm1::findXMLTag(char *XMLString, char* XMLTag, int XMLSize)
{
    void *found = XMLString;
    int XMLTagLen = strlen(XMLTag);
    std::vector<TForm1::Pair> result;
    TForm1::Pair pair;
    AnsiString XMLTagEnd = "</";
    XMLTagEnd += &XMLTag[1];

    while(found = memmem(XMLString, XMLSize - ((char*)found - XMLString), XMLTag, XMLTagLen))
    {
        if(found == NULL)
            return result;

        found = (char*)found + XMLTagLen;

        pair.start = int((char*)found - XMLString);

        found = memmem(found, XMLSize - ((char*)found - XMLString), XMLTagEnd.c_str(), XMLTagEnd.Length());

        pair.end = int((char*)found - XMLString);

        found = (char*)found + XMLTagEnd.Length();

        result.push_back(pair);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Just use a `vector<char>`.

Comment: Having some trouble understanding what this code does and what the question is.  I think you are trying to do in-place replacement of binary data with a base64 string, but I don't see that in the code shown.

Comment: Also binary data will work just fine with std::string.

Comment: @paddy: Still using vector<char> won't help me solve the replacement of the binary data, that is my main issue.

Comment: @Chris Olsen: Yeah that's what i am trying to do but i just can't figure it out how. And when i used binary data with std::string the output was not correct, it could be me messing something up, i am not sure. I've tried to use my binary data with an std::string and i've used the std::string.replace function but the data after base64 stuff wouldn't show after the replacement.

Comment: Are you saying that your base64 strings contain nulls?  They shouldn't.

Comment: If you show the code that you've tried already, even if its totally wrong, you might get more traction on this post.

Comment: No i am saying that some part of the first string contains nulls, because it consists of binary data. Then i calculate the base64 of that string and my intention is to place the new base64 data into the place of the binary data in my first string.

Comment: @ChrisOlsen: Since it wasn't working i deleted the code i've already tried. Well its ok i've just though of something that could work. Since i am using base64 my new string will have some overhead compared to my starting binary string. So i can use this fact to allocate a bigger string that can fit my base64 data aswell the rest of the original non-binary string. Then i will use strcpy and strcat to modify the resulting string.

Comment: Yeah it worked that way. I will post the code as a possible solution and if anyone could spot something that would cause a memory corruption please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating your C-style answer to C++, we are left with a *one-liner* which is safe (for valid indices), efficient and readable:

```
std::string binary_replace(
    std::string const& bin, unsigned bin_start, unsigned bin_end,
    std::string const& replace_with
) {
    assert(bin_start < bin.size() and bin_end < bin.size());
    return bin.substr(0, bin_start) + replace_with + bin.substr(bin_end);
}
```

This can be made even simpler by using the [`replace` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) for this purpose:

```
std::string binary_replace(
    std::string bin, unsigned bin_start, unsigned bin_end,
    std::string const& replace_with
) {
    assert(bin_start < bin.size() and bin_end < bin.size());
    return bin.replace(bin_start, bin_end - bin_start, replace_with);
}
```

(Take heed that `bin` is passed by value here since `replace` modifies it.)

Essentially there’s a direct substitute for most C-string functions in C++ – in this case, have a look at the [documentation of `std::basic_string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: This could be simplified even further with `string::replace`.  Or even replaced by `replace`.  :-)

Comment: Well i tried this version with some binary data into the string and it doesn't work. As soon as it meets a NULL char then it considers it as the terminating char for the string and i am getting an out of boudns error. I've tried the same code with a self-written string with a NULL char in it("Hi\0there") and i still got the same error when i tried to replace the "there" with something else.

Comment: @Stamatis You won’t get an out of bounds error in my code with a null character. How do you try calling the code? I suspect that you are constructing your string wrong: Directly assigning `"Hi\0there"` to a string object will truncate the string (because C uses `\0` as a terminator).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little self-contained example that might help you.  Note that there is no error or bounds checking, it's just meant to demonstrate a concept.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// stub for real base64_encode
std::string base64_encode(const string &data)
{
    return "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF";
}

// search without terminating on NULL
size_t binary_find(const string &str, size_t offset, const string &s)
{
    for (size_t i=offset; i<str.length(); i++)
        if (str.compare(i, string::npos, s) == 0)
            return i;
    return string::npos;
}

int main()
{
    string tag = "<data>";
    string endtag = "</data>";
    string xml("<data>\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0</data>", 23);
    size_t start = xml.find(tag) + tag.length();
    size_t end = binary_find(xml, start, endtag);
    string binary = xml.substr(start, end-start);
    string base64 = base64_encode(binary);
    xml.replace(start, end-start, base64);
    cout << xml << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yeah and Konrad Rudolph's solution worked just fine...I just had to use the string constructor with the numbers of the chars string(data, num_of_data) and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

```
char *binary_replace(char *binString,  int _strlen, int binDataStart, int binDataEnd, char* replaceWith)
{
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc( (strlen(replaceWith)+(_strlen - (binDataEnd-binDataStart)))*sizeof(char) );

    memcpy(buffer, binString, binDataStart);

    strcat(buffer, replaceWith);

    memmove(buffer+binDataStart+strlen(replaceWith), binString+binDataEnd, _strlen - binDataEnd);

    return buffer;
}
```

I know that this is not c++ but it solved my problem.

Comment: You can translate this solution 1:1 into proper, non-memory-leaking, safe C++ and get shorter, cleaner code. Not sure why you’d choose this route.

Comment: Because every thing that i tried using c++ failed so far and i need to end this as fast as possible and this is what it came to mind at the moment, so i am going to stick with this until i can invest more time.

Comment: See my answer then, and take some time out soon to learn about C++ string handling.

Comment: Thanks for that and i rly want to study some C++ but i don't have the time now :s